# How do I read the length of a value within an object?

Tags: javascript, object, ecmascript-6

I have this code below:

```
const minLocationLength = 1;
        if (location.description.length < minLocationLength) {
          reject(`Location must be at least ${minLocationLength} characters.`);
        }
```

I get the error `Cannot read property 'length' of undefined`. Am I doing it right?

Comment: Is `location` referring to the global `location` variable? It has no `description` attribute.

Comment: *"Am I doing it right?"* Well, if you get an error.... probably not ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value of description is not defined, you shall check like this first:

```
 if (location.description && location.description.length < minLocationLength) {
          reject(`Location must be at least ${minLocationLength} characters.`);
        }
```

Comment: well I just checked, it appears that its actually null. Then I found out that I imported my exported function with a typo. It was supposed to be 'LocationApi' but I put it as 'locationApi'.

Comment: Glad I helped :) @JoshuaRajandiran